# How do you use the number of reactions to trigger an if event in node.js?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to implement a simple starboard feature into my discord bot using the below code. However, there are two errors. The first one is "reactions is not defined" when using the whole code, and the second is "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined" when commenting out the parts not working from the first error (const stars and if (stars ===1))

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, member) => {
  if (reaction.emoji.name === `⭐`) {
    const stars = reactions.get(`⭐`);
    if (stars === 1) {
      const message = reaction.message;
      const guild = reaction.message.guild;
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#fee4b4')
        .setDescription(message.description)
        .setAuthor(message.author)
        .setThumbnail('A thumbnail')
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter('A footer');
      reaction.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === 'bot-testing').send(embed);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Reactions is not defined

[discord.js: MessageReaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction)

The parameter passed in the function is `reaction`, not `reactions`.

```js
if (reaction.emoji.name === '⭐') {
    const stars = reaction.count;
    ...
}
```

#### Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

[Discord.js: MessageReaction: message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message)

This error message means `reaction.guild` is undefined, instead you an do `reaction.message.guild`.

```js
const channel = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'channel name');
```

**Note: the event can be triggered on DM messages, not always within a guild**

Comment: That terminology for reactions is not defined makes sense but I used the following code and I got "null" as my console log. Why is that?

```const stars = reaction.count
    console.log(stars)```

Comment: If you are running into issues with `reaction.count` you could try `const stars = reaction.message.reactions.cache.get('⭐').count`

Comment: It still comes up as "null" with that code